# Writing a cross-platform application (Desktop & Mobile)

Tags: html, cordova, cross-platform, node-webkit, haxe

**TLDR;**

I'm searching for a method to develop a desktop & mobile cross platform app

**Long version:**

I'm working on a project at work for which I have built a nice node-webkit based app (found out about electron only afterwards). 
There is an actual need of having this app on mobile devices as well (tablets mostly).
We decided on html5 + angularjs, but nothing is set in stone.

The solutions I thought of are:

1. A single codebase which uses grunt to build the project files to later compile using cordova/node-webkit.
2. Haxe (which I only recently discovered).

**Notes:**

1. I believe native development is overkill in this case as the app is mostly informative with no "special" features.
2. I'm aiming towards having the maximum amount of code shared between platform.

Any other recommendations on a way to tackle this?

**EDIT:**

I decided to go with option 1 and from a single codebase compile to builds.

Reason why not use Haxe: Can't use JS on mobile the way we need it to while keeping the tech stack to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Your chosen solution would work well with Haxe, given the availability of AngularJS externs and Node being an officially supported target now.